# Hide soft deleted items in Yii

Tags: php, yii, soft-delete

What I'm wondering is:
is it possible in [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) to add some kind of property in a Model, so only items with the property `isdeleted` set as `0` are shown?

So I'm looking for a way, Yii would just ignore these instances of the items...
Something like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        array('isdeleted', 'shouldEqualTo=>0'),
        ...
    );
}
```

I thought messing around with `rules()` would be a way, but it doesn't work or I am doing it wrong...

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? While finding or saving?

Comment: I mean while finding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use scopes() for that.

```
public function scopes()
{
    return array('active' => array('condition' => 'isdeleted = 0'));
}
```

Then

```
$active = MyModel::model()->active()->findAll();
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to make the filter default, implement [defaultScope()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#defaultScope-detail) function:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array('condition' => 'isdeleted = 0');
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to override the default scope? So that MyModel::model()->findAll(); would already do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [W.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2198692/w-b)'s answer I knew to look into `scopes`, you can use `scopes` like [W.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2198692/w-b) did:

```
public function scopes()
{
    return array('active' => array('condition' => 'isdeleted = 0'));
}
```

and then use

```
$active = MyModel::model()->active()->findAll();
```

If you do not want to change your code in your project (like me) you can use:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array(
        'condition' => 'isdeleted = 0',
    );      
}
```

and then use

```
$active = MyModel::model()->findAll();
```